# how to delete virus file

Tags: antivirus

I have got an unwanted folder named " lkl " with a lock, on my ubuntu. I think this contains a virus as it is not deleting from my system. when I deleting it shows an error.[these files are shown when I opened this folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnPpt.png)How can delete this?

Comment: That doesn't look like a virus, it looks like a program's source code. Maybe the files are owned by root user so you can't delete them as a normal user?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine lkl is Linux KeyLogger ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lkl is not a virus but a keylogger. You downloaded this yourself probably?

Open a terminal and do a

```
cd ~/Downloads 
ls -l
```

and look at owner and group of the directory `lkl`. If your user

```
rm -rf ~/Downloads/lkl/
```

and if it is owned by another user use `sudo` but do consider re-installing as it could be active and it will catch your password.

Comment: bro... When I typed rm -rf ~/Downloads/lkl/ in terminal then it shows "permission denied".

Comment: How can I delete it from sudo

Comment: put it in front of the `rm` with a space in between, I would suggest a reinstall though: if it is owned by another user, aka root, it might be active and actively sending out what you type, including passwords.